# Pandas: Lambda Function using a conditional as well as an operator (Or, and))

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, conditional-statements, apply

I am working through my comprehension of lambdas functions as it pertains to pandas.
I am trying to create a new column based on if a certain word appears in column (A) ("Appeals","Audit","Assessment")

However I am receiving an error of:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

```
d = {"A":["Assessment Division","Division of Appeals","Calgary Audit","Halifax Market","Georgian Markers"],
"B":[100,300,400,500,400]

sample = pd.DataFrame(d)

sample["results"] = sample["A"].apply(lambda x: "Invoice" if x.str.contains("Audit") or x.str.contains("Appeals") or x.str.contains("Assessment") else "NoAction")
```

I have also tried this to attempt to shorten my code but receive the same error:

```
d = {"A":["Assessment Division","Division of Appeals","Calgary Audit","Halifax Market","Georgian Markers"],
"B":[100,300,400,500,400]

sample = pd.DataFrame(d)

reqs = ["Audit","Appeals","Assessment"]

sample["results"] = sample["A"].apply(lambda x: "Invoice" if x.str.contains().isin(reqs) else "NoAction")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any()` to check if the string contains any word from your `reqs`:

```py
reqs = ["Audit","Appeals","Assessment"]

mask = sample['A'].apply(lambda x: any(r in x for r in reqs))
sample['results'] = np.where(mask, 'Invoice', 'NoAction')

print(sample)
```

Prints:

```
                     A    B   results
0  Assessment Division  100   Invoice
1  Division of Appeals  300   Invoice
2        Calgary Audit  400   Invoice
3       Halifax Market  500  NoAction
4     Georgian Markers  400  NoAction
```

---

EDIT: One-liner:

```py
sample['results'] = sample['A'].apply(lambda x: 'Invoice' if any(r in x for r in reqs) else 'NoAction')
```

Comment: This is a very clever way of doing things and works perfectly. I suppose my follow up question would be if there is a way to do this using just the lambda function as opposed to creating a separate line?